# what's 1<<25 mean in open?

Tags: c++, c, linux

I am reading someone's code, and it has the following line:

`int fd = open(path, 1 << 25);`

which I can't understand, and I tried to google it, I also didn't find any answer, could someone help me with the meaning of 1<<25 here?

### EDIT 1:

I don't understand what happened here, why both the question and answer are downvoted.
It is other's code, it has a big code base, to rewrite it is almost impossible, and now the program has some bug and I have to fix it, that's why I am trying to understand every piece code, I am newbie in C and C++, I am not sure this is some trick I haven't seen before or it was a typo or something else. So I asked here, but just don't see any reason for both down-vote, could someone explain?
BY the way, as some comments points out, it works probably because it overflows to act as 0(RD_ONLY).

Comment: It means you should stop reading that someone's code, you won't learn anything worthwhile from it.

Comment: The second argument is `int oflags`. When calling `open` the macros defined in `fcntl.h` should be used.  `1 << 25` is probably an invalid value.

Comment: Thanks, it's from previous student and there is some bug inside so I need to understand the code to fix it.

Comment: @1a1a11a I guess you just found one, but I strongly doubt it will be the only one.

Comment: That is a bug in the code. This means nothing, and should not be used.

Comment: but actually it works when I read the content, no idea why

Comment: What is `sizeof(int)`? It's possible it's being truncated and the value of `oflags` is really `0` or `O_RDONLY`.  Also, are you checking whether `fd == -1` or `errno > 0`?

Comment: It probably works because it sets an unused bit, so it behaves like 0 which is `O_RDONLY`.  Clearly the rest of this code should be treated with the *greatest* of suspicion.  Another couple of errors like that, and I would just throw it away and start again.

Comment: Saying "but it works!" in a case like this is like saying "I went into a 7-11 last night and picked up a candy bar and walked out without paying for it and nothing happened.  Therefore it's okay to take things from stores without paying for them."

Comment: @FiddlingBits: If `int` has less than 26 bits, it is undefined behaviour, all bets off. It doesn't care anymore what/if code is generated anymore.

Comment: I thought on modern machine, ubuntu on Y510p, int should be at least 32bits? @FiddlingBits

Comment: Can you meow understand meow what I'm saying here?  Is it meow annoying when I meow insert weird random meow words?  But do you meow pretty much ignore them without even meow thinking about it?  That's probably what the `open()` call is doing when you hand it that weird random `1` bit up in the 25th bit position of its mode argument.

Comment: @Olaf: It's undefined for 26-bit `int` as well, since `pow(2, 25)` will not be representable in a signed 26-bit `int`.

Comment: @EOF:Off-by-one error due to counting from 0. You are right, it would have to be 27 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your second question, about the downvoting: It's
something like this.  The code you asked about invokes undefined
behavior, or something close enough to undefined behavior to
trigger everyone's undefined-behavior filter.

Now, undefined behavior is generally bad, but here on
StackOverflow it's super hyper mega totally awfully bad.  It's so
bad you're not even supposed to ask about it, you're just
supposed to instinctively know that it's bad, and never even
write code that uses it in the first place.  So you've been
downvoted as a punishment, to remind you to never ever talk about
or think about or ask about or write any undefined behavior code
ever again.  Let this be a lesson to you.

(Is this fair?  No, of course not.  And just watch: because I'm
taking your side here, this answer
of mine will get downvoted, too.  I'd post it as a comment
instead of an answer, but it's too long for a comment.)

(Others will explain that you shouldn't feel bad about the
downvoting, it's no reflection on you, it's just that this is
such a strange question that no one will ever ask it again, so it
doesn't belong in StackOverflow's repository, which is supposed
to be of high-quality questions that someone else might ask again
later and want to learn from.)

---

ADDENDUM: and now it's been put on hold as "too broad".  You're probably wondering what that means.

It's actually an exquisite question, in a perverse sort of way.  It's exquisitely confusing, and there are so many answers that they become incomprehensibly confusing instead.  Some people are telling you that `1<<25` was a mistake and happened to be ignored.  Some people are telling you that it was a mistake that made your program not work (despite the fact that it seemed to).  Some people are trying to figure out what `1<<25` actually means here, and they're the most confused of all, because of course it doesn't mean anything.  But to ask the question is to presuppose that it must have *some* meaning, so the confusion is almost inevitable.

Answer (score 0):

`<<` means bitwise shift to left.
1 in binary is written `1`, so the result of `1 << 25` will be `10000000000000000000000000` which could be written `2000000` in hexadecimal.

Edit: also I agree with EOF's comment to your question.

Comment: It's actually `0x2000000`.

Comment: I know the value, but I am wondering what does the value represent? RDONLY or ** | ** | **, have no idea what it represents, actually I tested it, it works on reading.

Comment: @1a1a11a it's only 1 bit, so it will be one flag at most, so no ** | ** | **.

Comment: `<<` is a _bitwise shift_ operator. The term "oofset is - uncommon - for this operation

Comment: @jdarthenay you are right, it can only be at most one flag, or it overflows as pointed out in other comments. I don't know why the question and answer are both downvoted.